# Need help on JQuery mouseover on menu with submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, menubar

I have this menu ([@ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRS7A/3/)) where this will happen given the following mouse events:

1. Hover on `Movies`
2. Then start dragging mouse to mouseover on `Movie library`
3. While dragging you accidentally touch the `Home` menu item
4. Causing the `Home` submenu to appear and hiding the `Movies` submenu.

This is not the desired effect i want. So im seeking some assistance. How can i solve this so that if im dragging my mouse and i accidentally touch some of the other menu options, the javascript will be smart enough to know that it shouldn't hide the selected submenu.

Can i add some kind of delay on the hover? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to throttle mousein/mouseouts events to prevent accidential firing (you need this I think...). Check examples on hiverIntent's site. You'll like it.

Comment: I'd like to keep the usage of external libraries to a minimum.

Comment: Of course you can check this plugin source and take what you want... At least you'll get some inspiration.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would integrate the plugin with my existing code? (if that isn't too much to ask)

Comment: OK. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/nilcolor/FRS7A/13/ Without hoverIntent tuning but it works.

Comment: See, hoverIntent mimics `hover` but with some nice additions. Its really good.

Comment: lol, that was simple.... i expected more than codechange in one line. Thanks. i guess this is my solution :)

Comment: Yeah ;) Its simple. You can tune hoverIntent using timeout/sensitivity/interval attrs to get exact result you need/like.

Comment: nice, however, i think the defaults works just fine for now. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this plugin fits exactly for what you want to do : http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want. If not, i'm sure it will guide you to the final solution

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('ul.menu').hover(function(event){       
        var hoverItem = event.target;
        //hide other ul's submenu
        $(hoverItem).siblings('li').children('ul').stop(true,true).hide()
        //show current submenu
        $(hoverItem).children('ul').stop(true,true).fadeIn()
    },function(event){
        //console.log(event.target);
        $('ul.menu li').children('ul').stop(true,true).delay(1500).fadeOut()
    })
});
```

Hope to have helped you. Cheers

Comment: No not quite. now i if hover on `Home` to get to `Movies` then only the home submenu is shown.